# Convert terminal commands to python script

Tags: python

How does one convert this terminal command to python?
Here's the code I have tried, and I need some help with it. The values I want to pass in are < | grep "http" > including the file itself, but I get an error for passing in more than one value.

Terminal command:
    `swfdump -a /home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf | grep 'http'`

Try 1:
    `dump = Popen(["swfdump", "-a", filename, "|", "grep", "'http'"])`

Try 2:
    `dump = check_output(["swfdump", "-a", filename , "| grep 'http'"])`

ERROR:

Try 1:

```
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (/home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf and |)
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (| and grep)
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (grep and 'http')
Couldn't open 'http': No such file or directory
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (/home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf and |)
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (| and grep)
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (grep and 'http')
Couldn't open 'http': No such file or directory
```

Try 2:

```
Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two. (/home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf and | grep 'http')
Couldn't open | grep 'http': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./SWFFile.py", line 62, in <module>
main()
File "./SWFFile.py", line 61, in main
trid()
File "./SWFFile.py", line 34, in trid
swfDump()
File "./SWFFile.py", line 48, in swfDump
dump = check_output(["swfdump", "-a", filename , "| grep 'http'"] )
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['swfdump', '-a', '/home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf', "| grep 'http'"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: It's an error with the arguments which you are giving to the command tool. Your Python program's okay, it's just the command which you are passing to `Popen` is flawed. Check it by typing it into the actual shell.

Comment: when i run the command in terminal i receive this : Can't parse opcode f8
what does that mean?

Comment: I have no idea. That problem is related to your `swfdump` command.

Comment: @PythonGuy Thanks, it turned out to be a problem in the swf file itself, ran it against another file and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe command `"|"` is a shell construct and is meaningless to python. When you execute `Popen` with a list and without `shell=True`, the shell is bypassed and the pipe symbol is just passed to the executing program as a command line argument. Confused programs spit out errors in return.

You could run through the shell either by converting the command to a string or by letting python convert the command to a string for you:

```
dump = Popen("swfdump -a {} | grep 'http'".format(filename),
     shell=True)

dump = Popen(subprocess.list2cmdline(
    ["swfdump", "-a", filename, "|", "grep", "'http'"]),
    shell=True)
```

Or, do the searching in python itself

```
proc = Popen(["swfdump", "-a", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if 'http' in line:
        print(line.strip())
proc.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in running a lot of external commands from Python, the result is simpler and more readable using the [`sh` module](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#piping):

```
from sh import swfdump, grep

grep(swfdump('-a', '/home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf'), 'http')
```

Note that grepping may be better done using Python than an external command:

```
from sh import swfdump

for line in swfdump('-a', '/home/cfc/swf/swf/flash2.swf').split('\n'):
    if 'http' in line:
        print(line)
```